# magento bot blocked my mailware due to guruincsite infection

Tags: security

my magento website got blocked by major browser and antivirus saying infected with mailware "guruincsite infection",

1: i deleted cached
2: deleted unwanted user
3: searched database by using keywaord of mailware code and removed it

still in footer i see some malicous code, 
how can i remove it

will i have to search in whole code

1: is there any tool in window to fix this issues as i am using shared hosting
2: measure to fix issue not occurs in future

Comment: It's not just you, thousands of sites are infected with that. Sucuri site will probably post a solution on how to get rid of that, check frequently here: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/10/massive-magento-guruincsite-infection.html

Comment: Unknown insertion method, could be a weak admin password, unsecure module, dead wordpress installation in the same hosting account or in the case of a shared server, low level hack on the server itself.

Comment: i have only magento website there also password strenght is good

Comment: @FiascoLabs thousands of sites are infected in a day, so there must be some vulnerability in core or 3rd party extension which allowed insertion.

Comment: Yep, and magmi is the probable culprit on a good portion => http://www.securityweek.com/thousands-magento-sites-abused-malware-distribution?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Securityweek+%28SecurityWeek+RSS+Feed%29

Comment: @mydeve do you have magmi on your server?

Comment: Being as it's a shared server, he may not, but another account may. The issue with MagMI is a path traversal vulnerability.

Comment: sorry no magmi.........

Comment: Of all GuruIncSite hacks, only 1.4% had an unprotected Magmi installed. So the cause was likely something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Willem's links are very good (see at the bottom).

I have written a blog post called "[How to remove Guruincsite Infection](http://www.minute.no/2015/10/how-to-remove-guruincsite-infection/)" that offers more detailed instructions how to remove the infection.

## Summary of removal process

### Dump the affected database and files

It's good if you want to do forensics later. Example dump command:

```
$ time nice -n15 mysqldump $DBNAME |gzip > ~/$DBNAME-hacked-$DATETIME.sql.gz
```

(Replace `$DBNAME` and `$DATETIME` with relevant values)

Out of old habit I always wrap my database dump commands in `time` and `nice -n15`. The former is because I am curious about how long time it takes and the latter is to ensure that the process is assigned a low priority - which is especially useful in production environments.

### Make backup of files

This is also in case you want to do forensics later.

```
$ tar -czf ~/hacked-files.tar.gz $PATH_TO_WEBROOT
```

(Replace `$PATH_TO_WEBROOT` with relevant value)

Above command will compress all files in your webroot and place them in an archive called `hacked-files.tar.gz` in your home folder

### Locate from where your Magento installation outputs malicious code

Magento can either render HTML from layout updates stored in database, CMS content in database or directly from files.

**Find malicious content in file system**

```
$ grep -r div123 $PATH_TO_WEBROOT
$ grep -r LCWEHH $PATH_TO_WEBROOT
$ grep -r guruincsite $PATH_TO_WEBROOT
$ grep -r willspointroofing $PATH_TO_WEBROOT
```

(Replace `$PATH_TO_WEBROOT` with relevant value)

**Find malicous content in database**

```
mysql > select * from `core_config_data` where `value` like '%div123%';
mysql > select * from `core_config_data` where `value` like '%LCWEHH%';
mysql > select * from `core_config_data` where `value` like '%guruincsite%';
mysql > select * from `core_config_data` where `value` like '%willspointroofing%';
mysql > select * from `cms_block` where `content` like '%div123%';
mysql > select * from `cms_block` where `content` like '%LCWEHH%';
mysql > select * from `cms_block` where `content` like '%guruincsite%';
mysql > select * from `cms_block` where `content` like '%willspointroofing%';
mysql > select * from `cms_page` where `content` like '%div123%';
mysql > select * from `cms_page` where `content` like '%LCWEHH%';
mysql > select * from `cms_page` where `content` like '%guruincsite%';
mysql > select * from `cms_page` where `content` like '%willspointroofing%';
```

If your site is affected you will most likely find something in your CMS home page or in `core_config_data`’s `design/footer/absolute_footer`

Make sure you remove infected files and database entries.

**Remove rogue admin users**

At this point it seems that injected admin users are the source of the injected javascript. To locate "rogue" admin users you can run this query:

```
mysql > select * from `admin_user`;
```

Then proceed to delete the admin users that are unfamiliar to you:

```
mysql > delete from `admin_user` where `email` = '$UNKOWN_EMAIL';
```

(Replace `$UNKOWN_EMAIL` with relevant value)

### Identify patches that have not been applied to your Magento site

After the ["shoplift" bug](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/04/magento-shoplift-supee-5344-exploits-in-the-wild.html) pandemonium, Hypernode by Byte created an excellent tool for scanning Magento sites for known vulnerabilites called [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com/). Use it to scan your site.

Then download relevant patches from [Magentocommerce.com/download](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download).

This document: [How to Apply and Revert Magento Patches](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html) describes how to apply patches.

### References

- [How to remove Guruincsite Infection](http://www.minute.no/2015/10/how-to-remove-guruincsite-infection/) (main source for this answer)
- [How to fix guruinc infection](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-fix-guruinc-infection/) by Hypernode
- [Magereport.com](https://www.magereport.com/) by Hypernode

Answer (score 3):

GuruIncSite removal instructions here:

https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-fix-guruinc-infection/

Check whether you are clean:

https://www.magereport.com

NB. Hackers got in through Shoplift or unused admin accounts. You should apply all relevant patches and check for suspicious admin user accounts!

Comment: _Our preliminary analysis of hacked Magento sites suggests that hackers have abused the Shoplift bug and unpatched WordPress installations to gain access to the Magento database._ Pretty much goes with the log activity I noticed on various dates mentioned by people. Another CMS they were actively attacking at that time was Joomla.